# EmguCV inserting new image to Captured Frame

Tags: emgucv

I want to to make a simple game like on screen will be some images and ,I will touch them with my hand .For this I must add some images to frame.I am using web-cam and Capture method

```cs
frame = cap.QueryFrame();
frame.Draw("Hello, world", ref f, new System.Drawing.Point(10, 80), new Bgr(0, 255, 0))
```

But I don`t know how can I add new image to frame . I added Some text but I need to add new image object to get coordinate of object and then move it . How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `ImageBox` control on your form by following [these instructions](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Add_ImageBox_Control). Then, just point the control to your frame:

```
imageBox1.Image = frame;
```

Now whenever you update `frame`, it should automatically update your GUI.